# How to set saturation of raster layer using PyQGIS

Tags: python, raster, pyqgis-3

I can set brightness of a raster layer with

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
contrastFilter.setBrightness(16)
layer.pipe().set(contrastFilter)
layer.triggerRepaint()
```

To set saturation I try:

```
ef = QgsColorEffect()
ef.setSaturation(30)
layer.pipe().set(ef)
layer.triggerRepaint()

TypeError: QgsRasterPipe.set(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QgsColorEffect'
```

How can I set the saturation?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `QgsHueSaturationFilter` class:

```py
huesat = QgsHueSaturationFilter()
huesat.setSaturation(30)

layer.pipe().set(huesat)
```